# console.log(event) TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: angularjs, events, console.log

Hope you can help me. I have a nested controller in the following form:

```
   $routeProvider
    .when('/something', {
        controller: 'XXXController',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/main.html'
    })
```

And then in main.html:

```
<div>
    <div ng-include="'app/views/list.html'"></div>
</div>
```

And in list.html:

```
 <td data-ng-controller="YYYController" ng-switch="active"><button ng-switch-when="active" data-ng-click="show_dialog($event)">
```

In YYYController:

```
$scope.show_dialog = function (event) {
    console.log(event);
    event.stopPropagation(); //so XXXController is not triggered
}
```

This leads to the error

> TypeError: undefined is not a function".

If I replace `console.log(event)` with `alert(event)` however I get

> [object Object]

which I would expect and would like to print to the console to identify the attributes.

Does any one of you have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This's strange. Things I could do, 1. re-check the spelling. 2. try to run the app on a different browser.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! Found it :-) Furhter down in the controller I had something like          function init() {;
         
            console.log = $scope.title;              
        }
         
        init(); This caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing two things here, alerting `event` is not undefined, however that object does not contain a method `stopPropagation`.

If event were undefined you would get the error:

> Can not call method 'stopPropagation' of undefined

The event object should be logged to the console, verify its contents.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. The error was caused by a subsquent init function. event.stopPropagation worked find. Cheers!